# unauthorized users on network

Tags: wireless-networking, ip

I've been told I have unauthorized users on my network: I've since removed my wireless router and just hardwired to my modem, but now I'm needing to clean the junk from my network...I don't know how.  Apparently I have an ip config conflict: a tech company wanted to charge me big bucks to do it, but when I asked if I could do it their response was," yeah, it's easy, I just can't tell you how.".....any help?

Comment: Could you give more details about this "IP config conflict"? If you're directly connected to your modem, and using DHCP, this should not happen.

Comment: When the tech company ran this "code" 8.8.8.8 -t   it showed literally hundreds of ip's, he said our ip for the router had been changed: and that there were hundreds of unauthorized users using our network...apparently my router didn't have a password on it (I know!)...anyhow, the router is now off, but I'm worried about anyone who has/had access to our computer...is there such a thing as wiping out any users?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is an IP address used by Google Public DNS. I'm not sure what command you could have possibly run involving it to detect "unauthorized users". Sounds like a scam to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the devices that are currently connected to your network and kick them off. Then you can block them by their MAC. Also I would suggest MAC filtering to only allow approved devices onto the network. Then you need to set a very strong password because, I can assure you that you will be a target for the next while as everyone around you knows that your network was unprotected. This tells them that you know little about networks and suggests that even though your network is now protected, it likely isn't protected very well.

Answer (score 1):

This is bunk.  If you have disconnected your WIFI, the network will "clean itself" in a very short period.   A network does not have much memory.  (The transient memory it has things like relationships between the computers [mac] address and IP address, and DHCP "leases" (ie what machine got what IP), but all of this will sort itself out with no cleaning up required.

The 8.8.8.8 thing sounds very much like a scam.